# Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare transaction

Tags: tridion

We are experiencing problems when trying to publish or unpublish certain pages and structure groups following a migration to from SDL Tridion 5.2 to 2011 SP1.

The publishing transaction is failing at the Committing Deployment stage, and is returning the following error message:

> Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed, Unable to prepare
>   transaction: tcm:0-682623-66560, null, null

The cd_deployer.exe service is also running at almost 100% CPU Usage around the same time.

We also get the following information in the cd_deployer.log and cd_core.log files:

```
2012-05-02 07:32:09,346 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-682520-66560
2012-05-02 07:36:36,071 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Prepare Commit Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-682526-66560
2012-05-02 07:36:36,071 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-682526-66560
com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Unable to prepare transaction: tcm:0-682526-66560, null, null
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.handleFailure(PreCommitPhase.java:120) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.PreCommitPhase.execute(PreCommitPhase.java:101) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_30]
```

Removing the component presentation from the page and republishing works OK. Using different component templates doesn't work, so the issue appears to be with the component somewhere.

Pages, binaries and DCPs are all being published to the file system. I did wonder if the problem related to publishing large binaries, however removing them from the component didn't make any difference.

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this?

Kind regards

EDIT: I have now tracked this down to a number of components which I am unable to publish or unpublish. When attempting to publish or unpublish the component, the transaction remains at the "Committing Deployment" stage for around 5 minutes with the cd_deployer service maxing out the CPU before eventually failing with the same error message.

If I create an identical copy of the component via copy and paste, this works fine, and goes straight through publishing in a couple of seconds with no impact on the server's CPU. Very strange!

EDIT 2: This is an example of what we currently have in our cd_storage_conf.xml file for each publication:

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="21_content" defaultFilesystem="false">
    <Root Path="D:/WebSites/live/Website/wwwroot/" />
</Storage>
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="21_data" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true">
    <Root Path="D:/WebSites/live/Website/Data" />
</Storage>

<Publication Id="21" defaultStorageId="21_data" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="21_content"/>
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="21_content" cached="false"/>
    <Item typeMapping="ComponentPresentation" storageId="21_data"/>
</Publication>
```

There isn't a specific type mapping for metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried un-publishing then republishing the offending  pages? This often solves the problem for me. I have a theory that sometimes an old failed transaction may have locked certain rows in the Broker. Un-publishing the page seems to free them up. This won't really solve the cause of the problem, but if it works it should help isolate the cause.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have tried un-publishing both the offending pages and components, but unfortunately the un-publish transaction will also fail and return the same error message, so I'm not able to do anything with them at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure how much further help I can be on this. If you can, I would consider restarting the Deployer and Databases. Also double check that there are no virus scanners interfering with the files (certain file extensions of MM Components maybe?). Also can you confirm what environment you are in, and what Java version you are using? Can you see how large the Publish Transaction Zip files are for the ones that fail when you publish?

Comment: The environment is running 2011 SP1 on Windows 2008 R2. The content delivery server is running java 1.6.0_30. The publish transaction zip files vary a lot in size. Small ones (between 1kb and 5kb) can still fail. Unfortunately restarting the deployer doesn't make any difference. I will check with our server guys about the virus scanners though, as this could be causing an issue. Would it be good practice to exclude the incoming directories from being scanned?

Comment: I have heard that it is considered "Best Practice" to not run virus scanners on the incoming directory  or on any file system folders to which you deploy files. Don't take this as gospel (your server admins my not agree) - but I have heard it from more than one source.

Answer (score 2):

Check your cd_storage_conf - are you storing all metadata into the same location? If not, modify so this is the case.

If you are still using a cd_broker_conf and allowing the system to transform to the cd_storage_conf, it would be better to create your own cd_storage_conf, since you are encountering difficulties.

Comment: We have created our own cd_storage_conf.xml file, and I have added an example of what we have for each publication to the call details above. As you'll see, there isn't a specific type mapping for metadata, only pages, binaries and component presentations. Should we add something like <Item typeMapping="Metadata" storageId="21_data"/> to this as well?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that in the deployer conf, there is a Phasing setting. For each deploy tag, a phase is defined, as to WHEN the deploy handler is fired: Pre, normal & post.

Not sure what the exact config is, but whe experienced the problem when we were setting up the archive manager.

Also, we had problems with deploying/transporting, when the temporary work directory was overflown with data. clearing the folder (default to: c:\temp or c:\work ) will speedup the process.

2 cents...

Comment: We are facing the same issue while ssetting up archive manager. Can you tell me doing what solved the issue